# Orbeon fr:map throws exception

Tags: google-maps, orbeon, sample

How do you display a Google Map in Obeon?

```
<fr:map
address-ref="address"
id="unittest-map"
longitude-ref="longitude"
latitude-ref="latitude"
style="width: 500px; height: 300px"/>
```

Testing the Form Runner builtin: fr:map in Forms Builder throws an error.
Exception in client-side code.
Message: xf_a6db6301b6c2f88cf6feeb281ad08189935d92d0 is not defined

The Xforms sample in orbeon/xforms-sandbox/sample/map-geocode shows the initial map, but also throws an error on use:
Exception in client-side code.
Message: GClientGeocoder is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing seems to be specific to that example, which uses the `GClientGeocoder` on its own. You can run `map-unittest.xhtml`, which also uses the `fr:map` and runs without any JavaScript errors in 2017.2.

Comment: As a side-note, I've removed `map-geocode.xhtml` to avoid possible confusions in the future.

Comment: I found this discussion from 2014
https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1053

Comment: Ahah.  I was trying to use reverse-geocoding by setting the latitude and longitude fields, the fr:map appear to require an address and outputs the lat and long.

Is there an fr:map option or address syntax to use reverse geocoding?  I tried variations on 33,-117,15 which should be near LAX airport at zoom factor 15.

I found the test code here:

https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/42ae3990409198153de7c6c716955dc7c85493ce/form-runner/jvm/src/main/resources/xbl/orbeon/map/map-unittest.xhtml

Comment: I noticed the lat/long ref only gets updated when you move the pointer, not when the address is loaded and the map is displayed.  How do you trigger the lat/long to update automatically when the address is loaded so they are in sync?

Comment: The behavior you're describing seems to be inline with what is [said in the documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/map.html). If you want the long/lat to be updated based on the address, then you'll need to modify the code of the component to call some Google Maps API that retrieves the long/lat based on the address, and store that long/lat, as is done now when users move the marker.

Comment: @PeterGruenbeck Have you managed to update the component for the long/lat to be stored based on the address?